How can I get all owner traits with vstest.console.exe?
I need to get all the owner traits from a DLL test file but I can't find a way. Is there a way to get them?
I tried to read the documentation but I can't find anything. I even tried the internal parameter "/ListFullyQualifiedTests" but nothing gave me what I was looking for.
